# Create DataGridView column that maps value from datasource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataTable`, which contains some data, eg. like this:

```
| id  |  name | type_id |
+-----+-------+---------+
| 0   |   joe |     156 |
| 1   | alice |      23 |
```

The data in `DataTable` comes from SQL-ish database. I also have `DataGridView`, which should display following:

```
|  name | type_name |
+-------+-----------+
|   joe |     admin |
| alice |      user |
```

I have a way to lookup `type_id` to `type_name`. I added a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and when it changes, I update the `type_id` in the underlying table:

```
    private void cellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // find the cell
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        string columnName = dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]?.Name ?? "";

        // check if combo cell is in this column for sure
        if(cell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell)
        {   
            // Only user type is subject to this event
            if(columnName == "type_name")
            {
                // BIG NOTE: THE LOOKUP HERE COULD (and is) BE MORE COMPLEX!
                // This is just an example for stack overflow

                object cellVal = comboCell.Value;
                // Only numeric values
                // Combobox displays string names, but contains numeric values
                if(cellVal!=null && IsNumber(cellVal))
                {
                    // change the underlying datatable, not the grid view
                    dataTable.Rows[e.RowIndex]["type_id"] = cellVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I would also like to have a vice-versa version. When the `DataGridView` loads, the values in combo box column are empty. How can I write a piece code that maps **values from DataTable column** to **DataGridView column**.

**Note:** In my real scenario, mapping is more complex than just number->string. Multiple values are involved. Therefore new column must truly be created!

Comment: From my tests, it is unclear what the function “IsNumber” is doing. If the combo box contains “admin”. “user”, etc… then when the line `object cellVal = comboCell.Value;` … will ALWAYS return a string “admin” “user” etc. You stated that _”I have a way to lookup type_id to type_name”_ … but I do not see this. Point being that according to my tests with the combo box, the method `IsNumber(cellVal)` will ALWAYS fail because the combo box values are not numbers. Can you clear up what exactly the method “IsNumber” is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what values “type_id” map to “type_name.” In other words, currently if the “type_id” is `int` 156, then “type_name” is a `string` “admin.” Are there other numbers from “type_id” that would also produce “admin?”

If it is a one-to-one relationship, then a `DataTable` with this mapping would work for a combo box and you would be able to map the combo box column directly to the grids `DataTable.` Example, if there is a one-to-one relationship then the `DataTable` for the combo boxes would have two properties, an `int` for the “type_id” and a `string` for “type_name.”

Fill the table with the proper mapping then set up the combo box’s `DataSource` to point to this table. Setting the combo boxes `DataPropertyName` to “type_id” will map this column to the same column name in the grids `DataSource.` With this approach, the user will see the “admin” “user” etc... in the combo box and if they change its value, the `DataTable` in the grid will update the `int` “type_id” value automatically. No need to set the value manually. This works if the combo box is set up properly.

An example of this is below.

If there is a one-to-many relationship, then there is another solution for that that I can post. Below is an example of what is described above.

The form has two `DataGridView`s. Both grids use the same `DataTable` as a `DataSource.` The top grid, only displays the two columns we want… “name” and “type_id.” The “type_id” column is the combo box column and will display the proper “type_name” for the `int` “type_id.”

[image]

The top grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event is wired up to update the `DataSource` on the bottom grid to show that the `int` “type_id” value changes automatically when the user changes the combo box cells value.

I hope this makes sense.

```
DataTable dataTable;
DataTable comboData;

public Form2() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataTable = GetTable();
  FillTable(dataTable);
  FillComboTable();
  SetGridColumns(dataGridView1);
  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
  dataGridView2.DataSource = dataTable;
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("type_id", typeof(int));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Rows.Add(0, "joe", 156);
  dt.Rows.Add(1, "alice", 23);
  dt.Rows.Add(2, "mark", 0);
  dt.Rows.Add(3, "sally", 44);
  dt.Rows.Add(4, "gabe", 133);
}

private DataTable GetComboTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}

private void FillComboTable() {
  comboData = GetComboTable();
  comboData.Rows.Add(156, "admin");
  comboData.Rows.Add(23, "user");
  comboData.Rows.Add(44, "database");
  comboData.Rows.Add(133, "system");
  comboData.Rows.Add(0, " ");
}

private void SetGridColumns(DataGridView dgv) {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  col1.HeaderText = "name";
  col1.Name = "name";
  col1.DataPropertyName = "name";
  dgv.Columns.Add(col1);
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn {
    HeaderText = "type_id",
    Name = "type_id",
    DataPropertyName = "type_id",
    DataSource = comboData,
    DisplayMember = "name",
    ValueMember = "value"
  };
  dgv.Columns.Add(combo);
}

private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Data Error: " + e.Exception.Message);
}

private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty) {
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dataTable;
  }
}
```